# Strange string concatenation on Python 2.5 in Windows

Tags: python

This code -

```
for ss_key in sd.keys():
    print str(sd[ss_key]) + ' ' + ss_key
```

prints the output as expected i.e. converts the int value of ss_key and prints the value and key on the same line.

But this code -

```
for ii_key in id.keys():
    print ii_key + ' ' + str(id[ii_key]),
```

prints key1 and then goes to a newline to print the value of key1 then key2 and goes to another new line to print value of key2.

Any pointers on this weird behaviour and how I can get the string concatenation right with key first and then value, Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do your keys have the newline character in them?

Comment: Is that trailing comma intentional? It makes the whole for-loop print into a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that `ii_key` is a string, and the newline is part of that string. Try printing `ii_key.rstrip()`.

Comment: I accept this answer. My issues also had to do with too many whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your data contains linefeeds or other unwanted whitespaces by adding

```
print repr(ii_key)
```

This will print linefeeds and other special characters in escaped form (e.g. `"\n"`).

Comment: Thanks a lot all. Yes. The trailing comma was intentional. Also, I fixed my problem by manually stripping all the spaces after the keys and now it is working fine. I had generated the text files by copying the data from excel file. I wonder if that added any extra spaces at the end of the keys.